# Combinatorics: Number of integer solutions with lower bounds

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions

How many integer solutions does the equation $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 15$ have, if
we require that $x_{1}\ge 2, x_{2}\ge 3, x_{3}\ge 10, x_{4}\ge −3?$

I need to understand in general what to do. I don't know the answer so can't check myself.

Comment: How many integer solutions does the equation $(x_1-2) + (x_2-3) + (x_3 - 10) + (x_4+3) = 15-2-3-10+3$ have, if we require that $x_1-2 \ge 0, x_2-3\ge 0, x_3 -10 \ge 0, x_4 +3 \ge 0$?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the same than to find the number of solution of $$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=3,$$
where $x_1,...,x_4\geq 0$. And this is a well know problem which it refer to the [stars and bars problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)). So, there are $\frac{6!}{3!3!}$ solutions.

Comment: Yes, though it might be worth saying $15-(2+3+10-3)=3$

Comment: @Henry: Indeed, thanks for your comment.

Comment: @Surb I checked by programm, here is 20 solutions. But I don't know how to prove it

Comment: Your problem is equivalent than to put 3 undistinguishables balls in 4 boxes. That is $\frac{6!}{3!3!}$. You can see this with bars and stars :$$***|||$$ (or if you prefer, to count the number of words you can do with $AAABBB$.@Prox